# How to create a CodeCommit branch along with a CodeCommit repository in an AWS Cloudformation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codecommit

I created the repo as shown below, but I want to add a branch with a specific name at creation time.

```
Resources:
    CodeCommitRepository:
        Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
        Properties:
            RepositoryName: !Ref Message
```

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:**

It is not possible to create a CodeCommit branch directly in the CloudFormation template using the resource `AWS::CodeCommit::Repository` AND there is no other resource available to do this either.

**Why**

IMHO: Because CloudFormation is an infrastructure-as-code service. So dealing with details of what's going to be running inside the infrastructure (or on it) should not be a part of the infrastructure code itself. But that's just my point of view.

**Possible Alternative:**
Write a Lambda function within the CloudFormation template, it should depend on the repository resource `AWS::CodeCommit::Repository` so you can use `DependsOn` while defining your Lambda function and set it to `CodeCommitRepository` like below:

```yaml
Resources:
  CodeCommitRepository:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: !Ref Message

  LambdaForBranchCreation:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    DependsOn: CodeCommitRepository
    Properties: 
      Code:
```

And then use boto3 to create a branch using [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit.html#CodeCommit.Client.create_branch) api call. Hope it helps!

**Reference:**

[CloudFormation Template Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) lists reference templates for all the possible resource types and their properties. The resource: `AWS::CodeCommit::Repository` is the only resource type listed under the [CodeCommit Resource Type Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_CodeCommit.html) and there is no property listed under this resource